# Refactoring repetitive calls to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I have a block of code like this: (MyClassX is just a shorthand for my business objects, which might extend later ...

```
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass1>().Wait();
conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass2>().Wait();
conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass3>().Wait();
conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass4>().Wait();
conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass5>().Wait();
...
conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass20>().Wait();
```

And would like to somehow refactor it to avoid the repetitiveness and make it more maintainable. One try was something akin to

```
 // Generic Lambda invocation 
 Action<Type> init_bo = t => conn.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTableAsync")
                             .MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(conn, null);
 List<Type> bo_types = new List<Type>() { typeof(MyClass1), typeof(MyClass2), 
                                          ..., typeof(MyClass20) };
 bo_types.ForEach(init_bo);
```

, which seems not terribly expressive (and does not call Wait()).
How could I go about utilizing templates/functional programming to get more expressive and concise code?

Edit: Not a duplicate in my opinion, since I already answered *how* to call a generic method in the original question, but I was not happy with the resulting code w.r.t. expressiveness.

Comment: Good question but on a sidenote.. Why are you using .Wait on an async function? That should be avoided whenever possible as it defeats the purpose of async.

Comment: What is so wrong with what you did? just put the "non-expressive" code in a function with an "expressive" name, and all is done, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @Joelius You are correct, I didn't write this code initially, so I just started the refactoring - I was still stuck on syntax instead of semantics :D

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Wait` by casting the result to a `Task`:

```
var createMethod = conn.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTableAsync");
Task[] createTasks = bo_types.Select(t => (Task)createMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(conn, null)).ToArray();
Tasks.WaitAll(createTasks);
```